# Visual studio debug tooltips

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I disable Visual studio debug tooltips?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using ReSharper that [displays](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/11/21/resharper-2017-3-brings-debugger-editor/) local variables, current line expressions and function returns inside the editor while debugging. You can disable it in ReSharper - Options - Tools - Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DisplayAttribute in your code, go in:

- Tools -> Options -> Debugging
- check "Show raw structure of objects in variables window"

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute):

> If the show raw structure of objects in variables windows check box is selected [..] then the DebuggerDisplay attribute will be ignored.